# Macro to remove all rows except those containing certain text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a Macro which will delete every row, apart from those which contain some specific text.

I need to have the following criteria:

- Never delete the first 2 rows
- Exclude the rows where the word "Somme" can be found in column C or D.

Note, the word Somme if part of a string in column C or D.  An example of the text found would be something like:

> Somme alpha/000284727819293

What I have so far is code which deletes rows with Somme in it, however i need the opposite:

```
Sub CleanUp()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D3", ActiveSheet.Range("D65536").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Somme", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Autofilter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s

Comment: I need to remove the content from the page rather than filter it out due to some other stuff im doing

Comment: Give it a try. I already have the code ready and assure you that Autofilter works :)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
Sub SaveSomeRows()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long, r As Range
    Dim s As String, v As String
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("D3", ActiveSheet.Range("D65536").End(xlUp))
    N = r.Count
    s = "somme"
    For L = N To 1 Step -1
        v = LCase(r(L).Value)
        If InStr(1, v, s) = 0 Then
            r(L).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next L
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

The initial version of the macro ignored column **C**.....try this instead:

```
Sub SaveSomeRows()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long, r As Range
    Dim s As String, v As String
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("D3", ActiveSheet.Range("D65536").End(xlUp))
    N = r.Count
    s = "somme"
    For L = N To 1 Step -1
        v = LCase(r(L).Value & r(L).Offset(-1, 0).Value)
        MsgBox v
        If InStr(1, v, s) = 0 Then
            r(L).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next L
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked for me (first example).  Thanks.